# JQuery UI Tabs - center

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm using the JQuery UI Tabs found on this site: https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#default .

Inside of my tabs I created tables with pictures. I wrote some css code to get the tabs centered however I would like to make the table (or the content) inside of tab body to be centered as well. I'm assuming I have to do some css to this class

> class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom"

Here is my JsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ubst2zxw/1/ .

To center the tabs I did this CSS class:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
    text-align: center;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li {
    float: none !important;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ubst2zxw/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the table, and not text. You need to center the table by using this code:

```
table {margin: auto;}
```

This works well now. Enjoy!

[image]

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7n4f1g9b/**

Comment: worked like a charm thank you for clearing that up for me that was much easier than expected. I went ahead and gave the table a class so that way I don't target all tables on my site!

Comment: thank you again! Had to wait the 10 minutes before I could accept it :)

Comment: @VinceMamba No problem. Just ask me if you need any further help. Happy to help. `:)` And gave your OP a vote up too.